# Can I backup Mysql 5.1 by copying all db files (*.frm etc)?

Tags: mysql

As I read here:
http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/450774-copying-table-one-schema-another

Will it work for version 5.1 ? Can I do so while MySQL is running ?

By the way I can only see *.frm, are others hidden ?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend writing a script to run `mysqldump` with the `-d` flag to backup schema.

If you want to show the schema, you can run `show create table table\G`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea for a number of reasons.  Your best bet is to use the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/mysqldump.html) tool.  It's very easy and produces a flexible backup file that contains all the sql necessary to re-create your database.

Answer (score 0):

FRM files only include table definition,

For MyISAM, data are on MYD files,

For InnoDB, on IDB files of on the ibdata tablespaces (on the root of your data directory)

But does not do backup by copying the files, that will be unusable.